# Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

So, I am trying to make it where every time I visit any nike.com sneaker page (without the HTML link), it automatically picks my shoe size, adds it to the cart, and checks out for me.

I am currently trying to use this script (below), but every time I go to the sneaker page, it does not properly add the shoe size I want, but just goes straight to checkout with nothing in my cart.

I'm told that I need to match the code to the actual page HTML, but I don't know how to do that.  Please help.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Nike auto-buy(!!!) script
// @include  http://*/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

var okayToClickAddtoCart = false;

//-- Assumes that size is a standard <option> tag or similar...
waitForKeyElements (".selectBox-label[value='10']", selectShoeSize);

function selectShoeSize (jNode) {
    jNode.prop ('selected', true);

    okayToClickAddtoCart = true;
}


waitForKeyElements (".add-to-cart.nike-button", clickAddToCart);

function clickAddToCart (jNode) {
    if ( ! okayToClickAddtoCart) {
        return true;    //-- Don't click yet.
    }

    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}


waitForKeyElements (".checkout-button", clickCheckoutButton);

function clickCheckoutButton (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

[Link to the "target page"](http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/?l=shop,pdp,ctr-inline/cid-1/pid-656545/pgid-656543)
[Snapshot of the target HTML](http://pastebin.com/6M7cMw40) (in case the target page is removed or changed by Nike)

Comment: `.selectBox-label[value='10']` is a jQuery selector.  It apparently does not match the HTML of the actual page. Disable the script, Browse to the page, Save the page from Firefox (**Ctrl** + **S**) as "Targetpage.htm", then upload that file (`Targetpage.htm`) to http://pastebin.com/ and link to the pastebin from your question.  Then we can help you tune your jQuery selector(s).

Comment: Here is the targetpage, http://pastebin.com/6M7cMw40

Comment: Here is the test page (targetpage) http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/?l=shop,pdp,ctr-inline/cid-1/pid-656545/pgid-656543

Comment: Okay, thank you I very much appreciate it. So, once you have figured out the code will it work on any Nike sneaker page, or just that one? As I want it to work on every nike.com sneaker page without knowing the pre-defined HTML link(s).

Comment: It should work on every shoe page with the same basic HTML.  Also, note that SO is not a script writing service.  But I noticed that there wasn't any one question I could point a beginner to to explain the process for  this kind of page.

Comment: I know that, it's just that I didn't know where to start, but I really honestly do appreciate you helping me with this! If you have a Paypal I can donate to, I will gladly do so.

Comment: Have you figured out how to do it? Sorry, if I am a bother. I just want to know the progress of it. Thanks once again!

Comment: Awesome. Okay, sounds good to me. I appreciate you doing this even though you don't have to.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Rather than just alter the script from the question, I hope to make a quick outline of how to script these kinds of pages and actions with Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey.

The steps are:

1. Take careful note of what you do manually.  Take special note of elements added/altered by the page's javascript, and the needed sequence of steps, if any.
2. Using *Firebug*, and/or Firefox's *inspector*, and/or Chrome's *Developer tools*, determine CSS/jQuery selector's for all of the elements you will read or manipulate.  This is especially easy to do using Firebug.
3. Use jQuery to manipulate static HTML.  Use [waitForKeyElements](https://gist.github.com/2625891) to handle nodes added or changed by javascript (AJAX).  Use [the Greasemonkey API](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Category:API_Reference) -- which is also supported by Tampermonkey and partially supported by Chrome userscripts -- to do any cross-domain page calls, or to store any values between page loads for cross-domain sets of pages.

---

---

## Specific example:

1. For [the OP's target pages](http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/?l=shop,pdp,ctr-inline/cid-1/pid-656545/pgid-656543), the OP wants to: (a) automatically select the shoe size, (b) add the shoes to the shopping cart, and (c) click the checkout button.

   This requires waiting for, and/or clicking on, five (5) page elements like so:

   [image: Set the size]

   [image: Check out]
2. Using Firebug (or similar tool) we obtain the HTML structure for the key nodes.  For example, the *SIZE* dropdown has HTML like this:

   ```
   <div class="size-quantity">
       <span class="sizeDropdown selectBox-open">
           ...
           <label class="dropdown-label selectBox-label-showing">SIZE</label>
           ...
           <a class="selectBox size-dropdown mediumSelect footwear selectBox-dropdown" ...>
               ...
           </a>
       </span>
   </div>
   ```

   Where the link actually fires off a `mousedown` event, not a click.

   Firebug gives us a CSS path of:

   ```
   html.js body div#body div#body-wrapper.fullheight div#body-liner.clear div#content div#pdp.footwear div#product-container.clear div.pdp-buying-tools-container div.pdp-box div.buying-tools-container div#PDPBuyingTools.buying-tools-gadget form.add-to-cart-form div.product-selections div.size-quantity span.sizeDropdown a.selectBox
   ```

   Which we can pare down to:

   ```
   div.footwear form.add-to-cart-form span.sizeDropdown a.size-dropdown
   ```

   for a reasonable selector that's likely to survive trivial page changes and unlikely to trigger on unwanted pages/products.

   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   Note that Firebug also helps us see what events are attached to what, which is crucial when determining what we need to trigger.  For example, for that node, I see:

   [image: Events for key first node]

   That link has no `href`, nor does it listen for `click` events.  In this case, we must trigger a `mousedown` (or `keydown`).

   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   Using a similar process for the other 4 key nodes, we obtain CSS/jQuery selectors of:

   ```
   Node 1:     div.footwear form.add-to-cart-form span.sizeDropdown a.size-dropdown

   Node 2:     ul.selectBox-dropdown-menu li a:contains('10')
               (But this will need an additional check)

   Node 3:     div.footwear form.add-to-cart-form span.sizeDropdown a.selectBox span.selectBox-label:contains('(10)')

   Node 4:     div.footwear form.add-to-cart-form div.product-selections div.add-to-cart

   Node 5:     div.mini-cart div.cart-item-data a.checkout-button:visible
   ```
3. Finally, we use `waitForKeyElements` to send the required events to the key nodes and to sequence through the proper order of operations.

The resulting, **complete, working script** is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Nike auto-buy shoes(!!!) script
// @include  http://store.nike.com/*
// @include  https://store.nike.com/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

var targetShoeSize  = "10";

//-- STEP 1:    Activate size drop-down.
waitForKeyElements (
    "div.footwear form.add-to-cart-form span.sizeDropdown a.size-dropdown",
    activateSizeDropdown
);
function activateSizeDropdown (jNode) {
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode[0], "mousedown");

    //-- Setup step 2.
    waitForKeyElements (
        "ul.selectBox-dropdown-menu li a:contains('" + targetShoeSize + "'):visible",
        selectDesiredShoeSize
    );
}

//-- STEP 2:    Select desired shoe size.
function selectDesiredShoeSize (jNode) {
    /*-- Because the selector for this node is vulnerable to false positives,
        we need an additional check here.
    */
    if ($.trim (jNode.text () ) === targetShoeSize) {
        //-- This node needs a triplex event
        triggerMouseEvent (jNode[0], "mouseover");
        triggerMouseEvent (jNode[0], "mousedown");
        triggerMouseEvent (jNode[0], "mouseup");

        //-- Setup steps 3 and 4.
        waitForKeyElements (
            "div.footwear form.add-to-cart-form span.sizeDropdown a.selectBox "
            + "span.selectBox-label:contains('(" + targetShoeSize + ")')",
            waitForShoeSizeDisplayAndAddToCart
        );
    }
}

//-- STEPS 3 and 4: Wait for shoe size display and add to cart.
function waitForShoeSizeDisplayAndAddToCart (jNode) {
    var addToCartButton = $(
        "div.footwear form.add-to-cart-form div.product-selections div.add-to-cart"
    );
    triggerMouseEvent (addToCartButton[0], "click");

    //-- Setup step 5.
    waitForKeyElements (
        "div.mini-cart div.cart-item-data a.checkout-button:visible",
        clickTheCheckoutButton
    );
}

//-- STEP 5:    Click the checkout button.
function clickTheCheckoutButton (jNode) {
    triggerMouseEvent (jNode[0], "click");

    //-- All done.  The checkout page should load.
}

function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

Comment: Brock you're awesome, it works flawlessly! Again, if you have Paypal, I would love to donate to you!

Comment: You're welcome.  You can donate [to Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/?src=userprofile#contribution) or [to the *Electronic Frontier Foundation* (EFF)](https://supporters.eff.org/donate) in my name if you wish.  The Adblock guy is also a generous and knowledgeable instructor of extension development.