# How to click a "Show More" link with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, ajax, click, greasemonkey

When visiting [a BBC episodes page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b01s352z), I would like "SHOW MORE" to be invoked from a Greasemonkey script.
I have tried half a dozen ways and none work. I think I am missing some fundamental.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common problem; See ["Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15048223/331508) for more details on how to solve this kind of thing.

Given that recipe, the only art/skill/difficult-part is choosing the right jQuery selector(s).  In this case, the "Show More" link can be reliably had with:

```
#synopsis div.copy a.show-more-truncate
```

So, the **complete working script** would be:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _BBC episode, click "Show More" link
// @include  http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

waitForKeyElements (
    "#synopsis div.copy a.show-more-truncate", clickShowMoreLink, true
);

function clickShowMoreLink (jNode) {
    var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ("click", true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

Comment: Brock, That was perfect. Thanks for all the detail. Love your waitForKeyElements.

Comment: The question was answered in a way that solved my problem. I don't understand how that was done if it was vague, etc. :-)

Comment: Read the FAQ.  In general, people want to see the code needed to demonstrate a problem and the code that you've tried.  It's true that I initially voted to close this question (as did 4 other experienced users).  But after I searched a little, I decided that this might serve as a simple "How to" that could help beginners.  I answered the question, upvoted it and voted to reopen.  If you feel the question was closed improperly, you can take it up on [meta].  But, I'd read the FAQ; read [**this link**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/) and edit your question first.

Comment: PS: I also edited the question to give it a broader applicability, but only you can show that you made a programming effort. And, it's your place to show the page's relevant HTML and/or other code.