# How to simulate a mouse click on an <a> tag that has no href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, userscripts

I want to use a userscript to automatically click on a button when a page is loaded.
The target page's HTML (which I do not control) looks like this:

```html
<a id="signInBtn" alog-alias="qb-signin-btn" class="signInBefore btn btn-24-white grid" data-disabled="false" hidefocus="hidefocus">
    <em><b>CheckIn</b></em>
</a>
```

It is a strange link without an `href` attribute. I am trying to use this code:

```
var btn = $("a#signInBtn");
btn.trigger("click");
```

But Chrome's console gives me this:

> Error in event handler for (unknown):
>   Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href^=/i?]

How can my userscript click this button?

Comment: `a` tag missing attribute `href` .And you can not call `.trigger("click");` because you have not define click handler for `a` tag .

Comment: Can you attach a useless `href` like `javascript:void(0)` to the link? Also, `"a#signInBtn"` is redundant, as IDs must be unique; just use `"#signInBtn"` instead.

Comment: @TusharGupta I am not sure. I am not famliar with javascript and html. I don't know why this a tag missing href.

Comment: @mc10 Sorry. I cannot find `href` in this a tag... I am confused.

Comment: @einverne you `a` tag must have `href` example `<a href="#"></a>` or `<a href="abc.html"></a>`

Comment: @TusharGupta I still cannot find any `href` attribution.

Comment: @einverne Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: @TusharGupta Thank you very much. I do know that `<a>` tag should have `href` . However when I read the HTML source code. I cannot find one href. Is there any other solutions that can avoid to use href ?

Comment: @einverne Use a `button` instead of `a` tag .

Comment: @TusharGupta I cannot change the HTML source code. HTML code is not written by me.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `.trigger()` is mostly only good for events set by jQuery.  And, in this case, it must be called using the target page's instance of jQuery, *not* the userscript's. (Also, how is your script using jQuery? The wrong method can bust the page, the script, or both.)

There may be other events required and/or AJAX to contend with, we can't tell from your question.  See [Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15052467/331508).

Polling for the node and triggering mouse event(s) will work in almost all cases.  Here's a complete userscript to get you started:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Auto-click the sign-in link
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

var signInTimer = setInterval ( function() {
        var signInBtn = document.querySelector ("#signInBtn");
        if (signInBtn) {
            clearInterval (signInTimer);

            var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
            clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
            signInBtn.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
        }
    }
    , 200
);
```