# Can only trigger mouseover event from TamperMonkey script via unsafeWindow - Why?

Tags: jquery, mouseover, tampermonkey

On an existing web page, via a TamperMonkey script, I want to automate hovering over an image, waiting for a "pop-up" (actually a < DIV >) to appear then clicking buttons on that pop-up.

Now from the console this code triggers a mouseover event as I'd expect and a 'pop-up' appears.

```
$('div.photo.mpHover img').eq(0).mouseover()
```

From my TM script, this code doesn't trigger the event unless I reference the unsafeWindow..

```
unsafeWindow.$('div.photo.mpHover img').eq(0).mouseover()
```

Why is this the case? I'm confused because simulating a 'click' event for example from the TM script works as expected without accessing unsafeWindow..

```
$('div.photo.mpHover img').eq(0).click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `.click()` and `.mouseover()` are just shortcuts for [`.trigger()`](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=trigger).
From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#entry-longdesc):

> Any event handlers **attached with `.on()` or one of its shortcut methods** are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired manually, however, with the `.trigger()` method.

And:

> Note: For both plain objects and DOM objects other than window, if a triggered event name matches the name of a property on the object, jQuery will **attempt to invoke the property** as a method if no event handler calls event.preventDefault().

What this means in practice is that:

1. `.trigger()`, or one of its shortcut methods, only reliably works on event handlers set by jQuery, not by other javascript.
2. `.trigger()` will normally only work when called from the **same jQuery instance**, in the **same scope**.
   A userscript operates in a different scope unless you inject its code or you jump scopes with `unsafeWindow`.
3. However, if the target element has a matching native method, eg `click`, jQuery will attempt to invoke this by default.
   Many elements have a native `click` method, but few (¿none?) have a native `mouseover` method.

   This is why jQuery `.click()` will *sometimes* work from a userscript, even if injection is not used.  But, this is not reliable and will often fail due to the security restrictions of trying to access JS code cross-sandbox.

---

The **most robust solution** is send actual mouse events (Updated code):

```
triggerMouseEvent ( $('div.photo.mpHover img').eq(0), "mouseover");

function triggerMouseEvent (jNode, eventType) {
    if (jNode  &&  jNode.length) {
        var clickEvent  = new MouseEvent (
            eventType, {canBubble: true, cancelable: true}
        );
        jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
    }
}
```

**Old method:**  Still works but [has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent).

```
triggerMouseEvent ( $('div.photo.mpHover img').eq(0), "mouseover");

function triggerMouseEvent (jNode, eventType) {
    if (jNode  &&  jNode.length) {
        var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
        jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
    }
}
```

---

This works in almost all cases and usually avoids the need for injection or `unsafeWindow`.

See ["Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15052467/331508) for more complicated scenarios.

Comment: It appears document.createEvent has been deprecated so I'll be reworking your code example to use event constructors, never the less thank you for taking the time to provide a quality answer Brock.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for letting me know about the deprecated code.

Comment: @richardPlester fixed. Edit submitted.