# Userscript stopped working with @grant and causes issues without @grant

Tags: greasemonkey

I've written an userscript for geocaching.com which switches the language automatically to a specified language (German), if English was set by an external app.
It worked fine until about 10 days ago, for no reason I could imagine.

If I remove `@grant` from the script, it works again, but causes several issues with the rest of the page.
Any `@grant` I tried, including `none`, breaks the script.

It's still working as it's supposed to do in Chrome. But I've already heard, Tampermonkey and Chrome are a little different than Greasemonkey on Firefox.

Any idea I can give a try is very welcome.
Here's the script:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     c:geo LangFix Deutsch BETA
// @include  https://www.geocaching.com/*/*/*
// @include  https://www.geocaching.com/*/*
// @include  https://www.geocaching.com/*
// @include  https://www.geocaching.com
// @include  http://www.geocaching.com/*/*/*
// @include  http://www.geocaching.com/*/*
// @include  http://www.geocaching.com/*
// @include  http://www.geocaching.com
// @exclude  http://www.geocaching.com/account/messagecenter
// @exclude  https://www.geocaching.com/map/*
// @exclude  https://www.geocaching.com/map
// @version  1.2
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

var TargetLink          = $('a[href*="LocaleList$ctl04$uxLocaleItem"]');
var LanguageSwitch      = $("div.LocaleText:contains('Choose Language')");

if (TargetLink.length && LanguageSwitch.length)
    window.location.assign (TargetLink[0].href);
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that **the `href`, that the script is trying to assign, is actually a javascript function.**  That is:

`TargetLink[0].href` has a value of `javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$uxLocaleList$uxLocaleList$ctl04$uxLocaleItem','')`.

Many browsers will still allow you to pass a `javascript:` URL to `location.assign()`, but Firefox has been restricting this practice of late. (See [GM bug 2232](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/2232),  [Firefox bug 1192821](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1192821), etc.)  This is especially true across sandboxes (`@grant` set to other than `none`).

A better practice is to [**click on such links by sending mouse event(s)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site), see below.

Other minor issues with that script:

1. The `@include`s are overlapping, redundant, and possibly a performance drag. The `@match` statement, below, should be all you need.
2. Likewise, the `@exclude`s can be condensed.
3. Some geocaching.com pages use a different structure for the language change mechanism.  I added an extra selector to catch an additional scheme.  (There is at least one more, rarer, scheme that is not caught by either script.)
4. Selector components like `LocaleList$ctl04$uxLocaleItem` are extremely brittle and liable to change on a whim.  Avoid these as much as possible.
5. Under some circumstances, that site loads many iframes -- leading to jQuery errors on some of the frames.  Use `@noframes` to block that and speed things up.

Given all that, this complete script should work much better for you than the old one did:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     c:geo LangFix Deutsch BETA
// @match    *://www.geocaching.com/*
// @exclude  http://www.geocaching.com/account/messagecenter
// @exclude  https://www.geocaching.com/map/*
// @version  2.0
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @noframes
// @grant    GM_xmlhttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

var EnglishPageIndicator    = $(".selected-language > a:contains(English)");
if (EnglishPageIndicator.length) {
    var GermanLnk   = $(
        ".language-selector > .language-list > ul > li > a:contains(Deutsch)," +
        ".LocaleList > .language-list > li > a:contains(Deutsch)"
    );
    //-- Don't try to assign a JS location!  Click the link instead.
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ("click", true, true);
    GermanLnk[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```