# Adding an element each time a popover is drawn

Tags: javascript, html, dom, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I want to write script adding one element to other element with particular id when it appears on page. It is added to a document when user hovers over other element.

In terms of business logic: when user hovers over user name, a popver appears. I want to add a button to a child in each of appearing popovers.

I've looked on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764551/automatically-check-a-checkbox-with-a-userscript) and resembled this construction with the code below, and it works. The issue is it checks only for one element, and when it appears, ends its work. I understand, that in order to check for every element, I should remove line `this.disconnect();`. That, however, only causes web page to hang.

What should I do to make it work? Am I doing something wrong?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         ms_teams_integration
// @match        https://example.com/*
// @version      1.0
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// @require      https://greasyfork.org/scripts/12228/code/setMutationHandler.js
// ==/UserScript==

var teamsIcon = ""; // icon in svg format here

setMutationHandler(document, '#user-hover-email', function(nodes) {
    this.disconnect();
    nodes.forEach(function(n) {
        var emailLink = n.getElementsByTagName("a").item(0);
        var teamsLink = emailLink.cloneNode(true);
        teamsLink.setAttribute(
            "href", 
            teamsLink.getAttribute("href")
                .replace("mailto:", "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users="));
        teamsLink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        teamsLink.innerHTML = teamsIcon;
        n.appendChild(teamsLink);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It hangs because your code causes a new mutation, which is detected again and again. To prevent it, check whether the new element is already added:

```js
    nodes.forEach(function(n) {
        if (n.__ms_teams_integration) return;
        var emailLink = n.getElementsByTagName("a").item(0);
        // ...............
        // ...............
        n.appendChild(teamsLink);
        n.__ms_teams_integration = true;
    });
```