# Can a tampermonkey script run in a Chrome pop-up window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

I am writing a little tampermonkey script to click a button called "Close Contact" in the Amazon AWS Connect softphone (used for customer service) if it appears because I keep forgetting to do it after calls at work. The problem is, the softphone is in a popup window. I can see the URL (although I will not disclose it for privacy reasons of my work), but as with most pop-up windows, you cannot even see the installed extensions. Is it possible for tampermonkey to detect / run scripts in pop-up windows like this, and if so, is anything special needed to do so? (I am mostly a python/java developer and am not particularly familiar with the DOM/front-end development beyond basics).

Comment: Find the URL of the popup window and use it in the script's `@match`. To do it, right-click inside the window, choose "inspect", switch to console and run `location.href`. You can also use `chrome://inspect` page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wOxxOm said in his comment: Yes, it can.

The most common problems can often be solved by wrapping your script in a setTimeout or using Brock's [waitForKeyElements](https://github.com/CoeJoder/waitForKeyElements.js) utility. Or, if you prefer, mutationObserver.

Links:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/1447509

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17872564/1447509

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39332340/1447509

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72667050/1447509

Comment: `IntersectionObserver` probably should be used instead of `setTimeout` in most cases