# How to execute function on page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

In the following I use this page for testing http://nitroflare.com/view/A71F0994E20F2E0/security-privacy.jpg

The below script clicks on Slow Download and removes the popup ad that shows up after the click.

Instead of clicking on Free Download, which will first popup a window, I want to call its second click function which is

```
function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#CountDownTimerContainer").show();
    startFreeDownload();
}
```

My script executes `$("#CountDownTimerContainer").show()` but it doesn't execute `startFreeDownload()` for some reason.

**Question**

How can I call `startFreeDownload()` which is on the page?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        NitroFlare
// @namespace   https://nitroflare.com/
// @description https://nitroflare.com/
// @include     https://nitroflare.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// @require https://greasyfork.org/scripts/5392-waitforkeyelements/code/WaitForKeyElements.js?version=115012
// ==/UserScript==

function SkipId(objId){
  var oId = document.getElementById(objId);
  oId.click();
}

window.onload = function(){
  SkipId('slow-download');
};

waitForKeyElements("div.superbox-wrapper", removeSuperbox);

function removeSuperbox() {
  document.getElementById('superbox-wrapper').hide();
}

$("#CountDownTimerContainer").show();
startFreeDownload();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById` returns a DOM node, which doesn't have `hide()` method.

Either use jQuery manually: `$('#superbox-wrapper').hide()` or use waitForKeyElements as shown in its example:

```
function removeSuperbox(jNode) {
  jNode.hide();
}
```

Also, since you're injecting your own jQuery into the page and use `@grant none` you may need to use jQuery.noConflict() if the site has its own jQuery.

Comment: The super-box is removed with the current script. I need to call `startFreeDownload()` somehow.

Comment: It may just be a timing issue.  Since you are using `@grant none`, try adding `startFreeDownload()` inside `removeSuperbox`, just after the `jNode.hide();` line.

Comment: That didn't help. How does the script know `startFreeDownload()` is the one on the page and not a function that I (haven't yet) implemented have in my script?

Comment: Look up javascript "scope". Anyway, there may be other requirements for that function.  I'd look into it, but I'm not going to help (too much) someone violate the business model (and probably the TOS) for a site unless I know that the site really deserves it.

Comment: @BrockAdams When you say scope do you mean `unsafeWindow()`? As for the business model for the site, I am sure it earns its money on piracy looking at http://nitroflare.com/affiliate . I doubt any content creator would be satisfied with only getting 10% of the pay. And anyone proud of their work won't have it distributed with popup ads. I only use it because I share files to myself on different locations where 1.2GB can be downloaded over night, so the speed isn't an issue for me.

Comment: Look up "javascript scope". And no, you don't generally need `unsafeWindow` when the script operates in `@grant none` mode.

Comment: @BrockAdams Ok, I am very stock here. Is it `window.startFreeDownload()` you mean?

Comment: No. If that would work, the code I told you to try earlier would've worked. Your script is not setting up whatever requirements are needed for `startFreeDownload()`.  Reread [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15048223/) for a more likely approach.  Anywho, this is the last I will respond to questions on this particular website/subtopic.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function (){
    $("#CountDownTimerContainer").show();
    console.log(0);
    startFreeDownload();
})();

function startFreeDownload(){
  console.log(1);
}
```

Try this It should work for you.

Comment: I don't see anything different compared to the script in OP.

Comment: For me its working..can you add a fiddle link so that i can have a look on your code..

Comment: Does Greasemonkey scripts work in fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/h39ztuv1/ How is that done?

Comment: Not sure whether it works still check this fiddle link 
http://jsfiddle.net/KDjqN/3/

Comment: Can you please add HTML for this fiddle

jsfiddle.net/h39ztuv1

Comment: As per this link jsfiddle.net/h39ztuv1  your function is getting executed @JasmineLognnes

Comment: Perhaps because it is in the same namespace in jsfiddle, but it doesn't work in GreaseMonkey.