# Shopping Online automation

Tags: javascript, automation

I want to create script to online shopping automation for this site.

link to product eg: http://www.lazada.com.my/remax-otg-micro-to-usb-adapter-pendrive-mouse-reader-ra-otg-forandroid-gold-10498828.html?mp=1&boost=1

with reference from this question ([Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site)). But as a person who got zero knowledge about JavaScript language, im here seeking help from those who able to help and share their knowledge here. Thank you in advance.

This is what i got so far, and i dont know how to combine them to make it 1 complete script.

Step 1. Add to cart

i.stack.imgur.com/Q7ugu.png

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('#AddToCart').click();
```

Step 2. Checkout

i.imgur.com/fqFqbEX.png

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".btn-checkout col submit_btn mtssel-cart-checkout-button").click(function() {
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', $(this).attr('https://www.lazada.com.my/checkout/step/index/')]);
});
```

Step 3. Login 
Prelogin

Step 4. Shipping

i.imgur.com/0HoZZWL.png

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('.shipping_btn').click();
});
```

Step 5. Payment(There's few payment option to be choose from tabs. I'll use paypall.)

i.imgur.com/tBENIEs.png

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tabs-Paypal").tabs();
$('#action').click(function() {
    var selected = $( "#tabs-Paypal" ).tabs({ active: # });
});
```

(not working)

Step 6. Place order

i.imgur.com/ESXR5Kx.png

note: dummy login (lazada123@stromox.com)(lazada123)

Question: So is it possible to do all the step with 1 click only using javascript? And how to combined all those to make 1 complete script?

Comment: So... what is your question?

Comment: Look into [Selenium Webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/).  We used this for integration testing of web apps.