# Tampermonkey to select a dropdown value. It has no ID or name, just a class?

Tags: jquery, select, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm writing a Tampermonkey code for a webpage like [ConverTo](https://www.converto.io/?v=fCU8VciNKe0):
It's supposed to automatically select the second option in a dropdown:

```html
<select class="format-select">
    <option value="mp3">MP3</option>
    <option value="mp4">MP4 (video)</option>
</select>
```

, several seconds after the page is fully loaded.
But nothing happens.

My code:

```js
......
// @match      https://www.converto.io/*
// @require    http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function(){
setTimout(test(),10000); 
function test() 
{ 
    $(".format-select").val('mp4'); 
}
})();
```

Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site).
Many AJAX-driven controls cannot just be changed; they also must receive key events, for the page to set the desired state.

In the *ConverTo* case, that select appears to expect<sup>‡</sup> :

1. A click event.
2. A value change.
3. A change event.

You would send that sequence with code like this complete, working script:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _ConverTo, Automatically select mp4
// @match    https://www.converto.io/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directive is needed to restore the proper sandbox.

waitForKeyElements (".format-select:has(option[value=mp4])", selectFinickyDropdown);

function selectFinickyDropdown (jNode) {
    var evt = new Event ("click");
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (evt);

    jNode.val('mp4');

    evt = new Event ("change");
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (evt);
}
```

---

<sup>‡</sup> There are other state sequences possible, to the same end.

Comment: Works perfect and thanks a lot, sir. Now I want to let it click the following "CONVERT" button, but I never learned anything about ajax, so I could only give it a random try mimicking your code --- waitForKeyElements (".btn lg btn-default convert-btn",....... { var evt = new Event ("click");    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (evt);}      It doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works.  You get 1 question, per question.  And follow-up questions, in the comments, should not "move the goalposts".  Don't be a [Help Vampire](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258279/331508). ... [Accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235); then upvote it; then ask your additional question as a new question. BUT, be warned that the 1st link, in the answer, already shows how to chain control activations.  Read and attempt to apply that linked answer before asking again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, works like a charm! You're the best :)