# Tampermonkey select a dropdown value with name

Tags: jquery, tampermonkey

I want Tampermonkey to change a select drop down to a specific country. The HTML is formatted like;

```
  <label>Country</label>
    <span class="select_wrapper">
      <select name="shipping_country_id">
        <option value="46">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="47">Albania</option>
        <option value="42">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="43" selected="">United States</option>
      </select>
      <span class="value">United States</span>
    </span>
```

I have tried;

```
("select[name='shipping_country_id'] option[value='42']", clickNode, true);
```

and

```
 (document.querySelector && document.querySelector('select[name="shipping_country_id"]') || []).value = '42';
```

After reading [Tampermonkey to select a dropdown value. It has no ID or name, just a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421019/tampermonkey-to-select-a-dropdown-value-it-has-no-id-or-name-just-a-class)
I tried using the same method used in that answer;

```
    waitForKeyElements ("shipping_country_id:has(option[value='42'])", selectCountryDropdown);

function selectCountryDropdown (jNode) {
var evt = new Event ("click");
jNode[0].dispatchEvent (evt);

jNode.val('42');

evt = new Event ("change");
jNode[0].dispatchEvent (evt);
}
```

Am I missing something or trying the wrong thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work by using a similar method to the last posted in the question, was just a syntax error.

```
waitForKeyElements ("select[name=shipping_country_id]:has(option[value=42])", selectCountryDropdown);


function selectCountryDropdown (jNode) {
var evt = new Event ("click");
jNode[0].dispatchEvent (evt);

jNode.val('42');

evt = new Event ("change");
jNode[0].dispatchEvent (evt);
}
```