# call a site function from tampermonkey userscript

Tags: greasemonkey, raspberry-pi2

I need to recall of a function from a site which has a pull-down menu run by java (http://opac.uniurb.it/SebinaOpac/Opac.do#0); We must force the site to select a variable (sistema bibliotecario di Pesaro --> Rete dei Centri Documentazione Handicap from the Seleziona la tua biblioteca )
In other world, I have to change the

```
<div class ='div.biblioss2'>
```

from

```
<input type="text" id="bibliosel2" placeholder="Seleziona la tua biblioteca" data-init="true" autocomplete="off" aria-hidden="false" style="display: inline-block;" data-syw-done="biblioss" aria-expanded="true">
```

to

```
<input type="text" id="bibliosel2" placeholder="Rete dei Centri Documentazione Handicap" data-init="true" autocomplete="off" aria-hidden="false" style="display: inline-block;" data-syw-done="biblioss" aria-expanded="true">
```

That then everything is reduced to make the 'placeholder' value change...

I'm trying to create a tampermonkey script that runs on Chromium on a Raspberry PI2 with Rasbian, but I have no idea how to do it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your goal? Also, I visited the site and I see no input fields.

Comment: @TomášZato, the inputs are there in a "comboselect floater".  This means that you would essentially use the techniques of [Q15048223](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15048223) to click two controls sequentially (if the value was not already set, and possibly handling additional settling). ... So, this Q is not quite a duplicate.

Comment: @BrockAdams I don't think it's a duplicate, I think it shows zero research effort. I didn't vote to close it (neither did anyone else).

Comment: @TomášZato, ***I*** was looking to hammer it as a dupe.  As for research effort, that's true-ish of almost every "Newbie" question, but not bad enough in this case to downvote, I think.  (Linking to the site and snipping relevant HTML is half the battle in GM/TM questions.)

Comment: Meanwhile, I thank you for the time lost. I am an educator in a disabled adult Center where we are trying to manage a library and we need that Chromium showes our library catalogue and not the entire Province one  (we are in Italy).
And I am  totally ignorant of javascript.

Comment: @TomášZato    I've tried with Q443430, Q5006460 and Q22707808. But I don't know anything how to compilate the code. I probably should study more and at this time rely on paying someone. However, I'm trying to use the replace command to replace the variable "biblioss2" with the "placeholder=rete dei centri ecc." But I do not know the right syntax.

Comment: @Brock-Adams, I've searched the code and I think I found the code part I need to. `},
    "URBDH": {
      "c": "URBDH",
      "d": "Rete dei Centri Documentazione Handicap",
      "i": true,
      "k": "BIB",
      "o": 760,
      "s": [
        false,
        false
      ],
      "v": true` ...line1564 in the html code... Now, how can I recall this info in the opening of the html page?

Comment: You don't; that won't work.  You have the script click on the controls the same way you would, or have it auto redirect to the correct page, if possible.