# How do I automatically click this button with tampermonkey?

Tags: tampermonkey

I am wondering how I can make a script that automatically clicks a button with tampermonkey.

Here is the button:

```
<button class="confirm" tabindex="1" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(91, 155, 209); box-shadow: rgba(91, 155, 209, 0.8) 0px 0px 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 0px 0px 1px inset;">Next Video</button>
```

Comment: Did you look already some manuals how it should be done? Why manual instructions did not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button:contains('Next Video')").click();
});
```

Hope that helps!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#result").hide();
  $("#btnNextVideo").trigger('click');

$("#btnNextVideo").click(function() {
   $("#result").show();
});
});
</script>


<button id="btnNextVideo" class="confirm" tabindex="1" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(91, 155, 209); box-shadow: rgba(91, 155, 209, 0.8) 0px 0px 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 0px 0px 1px inset;">Next Video</button>

<div id="result">
It worked!
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#result").hide();
  $("#btnNextVideo").trigger('click');

$("#btnNextVideo").click(function() {
   $("#result").show();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please help me!

Comment: Hi @Yimin, I have added a runnable code sample to show you it working.