# Why is this userscript only doing the first if?

Tags: javascript, userscripts, tampermonkey

I am working on a User script but it seems to work just for the first comparison:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var noError = document.getElementsByClassName("noMistakeButton");
var next = document.getElementsByClassName("nextButton");
var wait = document.getElementsByClassName("understoodButton");
var okko = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonKo");
var exitOkko = document.getElementsByClassName("exitButton");

while(1)
{
    if( noError !== null)
    {
        noError.click();
    }

    if( next !== null)
    {
        exit.click();
    }

    if( wait !== null)
    {
        wait.click();
    }
    sleep(2);
    if( okko !== null)
    {
        exit.click();
    }

    if( exitOkko !== null)
    {
        exitOkko.click();
    }

} })();
```

My goal is the run this script freely while AFK.
There are, as you can see, many buttons on the web page and each button cant be :visible or :hidden. My goal is just to click on them.

[Here is the target page (static URL)](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/voltaire/com.woonoz.gwt.woonoz.Voltaire/Voltaire.html?returnUrl=https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/).

Some buttons only have class and no ID. Others have them both.

The console reports:

> ERROR: Execution of script 'AutoVoltair' failed!   noError.click is not
>   a function

Comment: Does your console tell you anything?

Comment: The first `if (...)` is the same as `if (true)` and the code in its block won't do anything but throw an error.

Comment: "ERROR: Execution of script 'AutoVoltair' failed! noError.click is not a function" the console is telling me that

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? It seems like sort of fraud to me.

Comment: not fraud, i just want to replace mouse clicking buy scripting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you hope to accomplish.  If you are trying to step through a sequence of controls, use the approach illustrated in [Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site).

The kind of code shown in the question would just play "Whac-A-Mole" with whatever button "popped up" next. (And only if the preceding buttons had been deleted.)

Anyway, **to answer the question: "why this code is only doing the first if?".**

It's because userscripts (and javascript) stop running at the first critical error <sup>(with a few exceptions)</sup>.  Additionally:

- `noError.click` is not a function because [noError is a collection of elements, not a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method).
- All the `getElementsByClassName` calls are only done once.  If it's going to continually loop, you need to recheck inside the loop.
- There is no such thing as `sleep()`.
- `while (1)` is a very bad idea and can freeze your browser, or even help crash your PC.  Use `setInterval` for polling the page.

Here's the "Whac-A-Mole" code with those errors corrected:

```
setInterval ( () => {
        var noError     = document.getElementsByClassName ("noMistakeButton");
        var next        = document.getElementsByClassName ("nextButton");
        var wait        = document.getElementsByClassName ("understoodButton");
        var okko        = document.getElementsByClassName ("buttonKo");
        var exitOkko    = document.getElementsByClassName ("exitButton");

        if (noError.length) {
            noError[0].click ();
        }
        if (next.length) {
            next[0].click ();
        }
        if (wait.length) {
            wait[0].click ();
        }
        if (okko.length) {
            okko[0].click ();
        }
        if (exitOkko.length) {
            exitOkko[0].click ();
        }
    },
    222  //  Almost 5 times per second, plenty fast enough
);
```

**If you want to sequence clicks, use chained `waitForKeyElements()` calls** as shown in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15052467/331508).