# Tampermonkey Checkbox stops working after reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts, tampermonkey

I am using this Tampermonkey code to create checkboxes that, when checked,  will click on some buttons periodically as well as refresh the page.
That code does the right thing, the problem is that after updating the page it would uncheck the checkboxes and stop.

I managed to make the checkboxes remain checked with the last part of the code, the problem is that after updating the page it does not continue the functions even with the checkbox checked, and from what I observed with tests I have to uncheck the checkbox and check again to work.

I believe the problem is with the start of the code but I could not fix this after searching everywhere. From what I saw it only responds if it is clicked on the checkbox and not if it is automatically checked.

```
function addDomElements () {
    var newNodes = $( `
      <div class="mySpamCntrols foundation-radius fightContainer foundation-base-font">
        <input type="checkbox" class="smallerBox" id="EsquerdaHitBox" data-trgtSelctr="#fightButtonBerserk1">
        <label class="checkboxlabel" for="EsquerdaHitBox">Hit Esquerda</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="smallerBox" id="MeioHitBox" data-trgtSelctr="#fightButtonBerserk1">
        <label class="checkboxlabel" for="MeioHitBox">Hit Meio</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="smallerBox" id="DireitaHitkBox" data-trgtSelctr="#fightButtonBerserk2">
        <label class="checkboxlabel" for="DireitaHitkBox">Hit Direita</label>
      </div>
    ` );
    //-- Best to add a <style> node, but spam inline styles for now...
    newNodes.find ("input").attr ("style", "margin:1px !important;line-height:10px !important;");
    newNodes.find ("label").attr ("style", "margin-right: 20px;");

    newNodes.insertAfter($('.foundation-radius.fightContainer.foundation-base-font')[1] );

    //-- Activate checkboxes
    $(".mySpamCntrols").on ("change", "input[data-trgtSelctr]", processMyCheckBoxes);
}
addDomElements ();

function processMyCheckBoxes (zEvent) {
    var chkBox = zEvent.target;
    //-- If box is now checked, fire off an immediate click and start the timers
    if (chkBox.checked) {
        clickButtonByjQuerySelector (chkBox.dataset.trgtselctr);
        //chkBox.spamClckTmr   = setInterval (clickButtonByjQuerySelector, 30000, chkBox.dataset.trgtselctr);
        chkBox.spamClckTmr   = setInterval (clickButtonByjQuerySelector, 2222, chkBox.dataset.trgtselctr);
        chkBox.pageReloadTmr = setTimeout  (location.reload.bind (window.location), 300000);
    }
    //-- Else, if box is now not checked, cancel the timers
    else {
        clearInterval (chkBox.spamClckTmr);
        clearTimeout  (chkBox.pageReloadTmr);
    }
}

function clickButtonByjQuerySelector (jQuerySelector) {
    var targetNode = $(jQuerySelector)[0];
    if (targetNode) {
        console.log ("Clicking node: ", jQuerySelector);
        //-- Warning this my not always suffice.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15048223
        targetNode.click ();
    }
    else {
        console.warn (`Node [${jQuerySelector}] not found!`);
    }
}

//Save Checkbox
$(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').each(function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.prop('checked', sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] === 'true');
    });

    $('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
        var $el = $(this);
        sessionStorage[$el.prop('id')] = $el.is(':checked');
    });
});
```

How do I get the selected checkbox timers to restart after the page is reloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but it's not enough to set the `checked` property. You must also sync up the event handler(s).

An easy way to to that is just have the code click the checkboxes.

Also, there is no need/use for that `$(function(){` wrapper.

This code works:

```
//-- Restore and Save Checkboxes from sessionStorage:
$('input:checkbox').each (function () {
    var $el     = $(this);
    var elId    = $el.prop ('id');
    if (sessionStorage[elId] === 'true') {
        document.getElementById (elId).click ();
    }
} );

$('input:checkbox').on ('change', function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    sessionStorage[$el.prop ('id')] = $el.is (':checked');
} );
```