# Clicking a bunch of buttons that need to wait on Ajax calls before proceeding with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have an HTML structure that essentially looks like an example I provide below. I am trying to iterate over each `li` using jquery's `.each()` which is working fine. I then want to try and click each "buy" button which is also working.

Here is where the struggles begin. When the buy is clicked an AJAX call is made to check if the item is still available, and then the confirmation div is shown (confirmation div is seen in code below). I would then like to click the "Yes" to confirm the transaction (already have the trigger working here). Before proceeding to the next `li` however I need to again wait for this ajax call to finish.

Is there a way to go about this properly?

Basic HTML setup on the website:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="item-name">Some item</div>
        <span class="buy-item">Buy</span>
        <div class="confirm-buy"></div>  //EMPTY UNTIL AJAX DONE, when Done this div is filled
        <div class="success-buy"></div>  //EMPTY UNTIL AJAX DONE for buy confirmation, when Done this div is filled
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-name">Some item</div>
        <span class="buy-item">Buy</span>
        <div class="confirm-buy"></div>  //EMPTY UNTIL AJAX DONE, when Done this div is filled
        <div class="success-buy"></div>  //EMPTY UNTIL AJAX DONE for buy confirmation, when Done this div is filled
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="item-name">Some item</div>
        <span class="buy-item">Buy</span>
        <div class="confirm-buy"></div>  //EMPTY UNTIL AJAX DONE, when Done this div is filled
        <div class="success-buy"></div>  //EMPTY UNTIL AJAX DONE for buy confirmation, when Done this div is filled
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript (example, may not exactly match the HTML sample above)

```
$(document).on("click", "button.buyAllOfIt", function() {
    //Iterate over each list item
    $("li").each(function() { 
        //Click the initial "buy" button:
        $(this).find('span.buy-item').trigger('click');

        //Click the confirmation "Yes" that pops up after the ajax finishes from above click:
        $(this).find('a.yes-buy').trigger('click');

        //Now it should wait until the above ajax finishes before it continues to
        // "trigger" the next "Buy" click in the next list item!
    });
});
```

Essentially I just want to iterate over each of the `li` elements, and then wait at two different points before continuing. When `.confirm-buy` has text added into it in the current `li` then it should continue (it will click a `buy` confirmation), then it should wait again, but this time for `.success-buy` to be filled. Then it should continue to the next `li`.

I am stumped on how to handle all of this waiting, especially while inside a `.each()`.

Edit: Here is an example of the steps in picture form:

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

[image: step 3]

Comment: Can you post your current code that isn't running in the right order? The tweak *should* be pretty trivial

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have added in some example code of what I have currently. However this does not work properly as it assumes everything happens right away which is not the case because of the async ajax going on within the site when these clicks are made.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site.  See there for technique that will get much of the job done.

Comment: @BrockAdams I managed to rework my code a bit and get that to work for this!

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad that answer was useful to you.

Answer (score -1):

You could render the li from javascript dynamically.  You need to have a method which calls the API which provides you whether the item is available or not.  Inside the callback function of the API call add your render method.  This method runs a for loop which adds li and then renders into the UI.

The best practice is to have a one single alert boxes for Confirm box and Success box.

Use an ID for each li and call the confirm and success method with the respective ids to a method that renders confirm and later success into the UI.

Comment: Not sure if you noticed but I have Greasemonkey tags on this question. I do not have access to all from the backend of the site. I have to work with what I've got in terms of the website. I am trying to add this via a Tampermonkey script so the Ajax call way of them doing things is what I have to work with.

Comment: I have added some sample Javascript code I am using now too if that helps.