# Set a delay between each click in loop

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I would like to simply set a delay between each click.
Shown below is the script I created. It works fine with clicking each element the way I want it to. The problem is that it clicks each element almost at the same time causing me horrible lag.

Original Code.

```
var timerVar = setInterval (function() {DoMeEverySecond (); }, 5000); // 
<< set to 2 seconds.

function DoMeEverySecond ()
{
(function() {
document.getElementsByName("zTab")[0].click();
document.getElementsByName("zButton")[0].click();
document.getElementsByName("zClose")[0].click();
})();
}
```

Would it be possible to do something like this.

```
var timerVar = setInterval (function() {DoMeEverySecond (); }, 5000); // 
<< set to 2 seconds.

function DoMeEverySecond ()
{
(function() {
document.getElementsByName("zTab")[0].click();
-----------A DELAY HERE!-----------
document.getElementsByName("zButton")[0].click();
---------- ANOTHER ONE HERE! ----------------
document.getElementsByName("zClose")[0].click();
})();
}
```

The code is very simple, I tried to explain it as best as I could. Could someone help me out on this piece of code

Comment: In general, that is a very brittle and fiddly way to do things. Better to use [a different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a live demo of a potential solution. See the inline comments:

```js
// Lets just add some logging here for when the buttons are clicked
document.querySelectorAll('.z-tab').forEach(element => {            
  element.addEventListener('click', e => console.log('Z Tab'));
});

document.querySelectorAll('.z-button').forEach(element => {            
  element.addEventListener('click', e => console.log('Z Button'));
});

document.querySelectorAll('.z-close').forEach(element => {            
  element.addEventListener('click', e => console.log('Z Close'));
});

// Let's take advantage of async/await 
async function DoMeEverySecond () {
  const elementClassNames = ['.z-tab', '.z-button', '.z-close'];

  for (let i = 0; i < elementClassNames.length; i++) {
    const element = document.querySelectorAll(elementClassNames[i])[0];
    await delayFor(1000); // Let's wait 1000ms between each click
    element.click()
  }
}

// Delay function that will resolve a promise after the setTimeout delay has been passed.
function delayFor(delay) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, delay);
  });
}
DoMeEverySecond ();
```

```html
<h2>Z Tabs</h2>
<button class="z-tab">1</button> <button class="z-tab">2</button>

<h2>Z Buttons</h2>
<button class="z-button">1</button> <button class="z-button">2</button>

<h2>Z Close</h2>
<button class="z-close">1</button> <button class="z-close">2</button>
```

Comment: Note that the previous stackblitz demo (A) is no longer needed and (B) trips errors in my browser when clicking the buttons.

Comment: Also, this answer currently is using `class`, but the OP requires the `name` attribute be used (and can't change the target HTML because it's a Tampermonkey scenario).

Answer (score 1):

Shure you can add delays, but as @Brock Adams mentioned, better use a different approach, like a promise-chain, to be shure all clicks were triggered, before looping again.

I assume a delay of 1 second, you can change this, but be aware, that if you add a delay in total of more that 5 seconds, the click-actins will overlap per interval.

So your code with delays:

```
function doMeInInterval () {
  document.querySelector("[name=zTab]").click();
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector("[name=zButton]").click();
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.querySelector("[name=zClose]").click();
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
}
var timerVar = setInterval(doMeInInterval, 5000);
```

Comment: Hey, Yours is working pretty good, i'm just having a error. It's not fully clicking on all of the elements I listed.

Comment: @Sparklestheunicorn The error you are talking about could result from a bunch of things. Can you provide a fiddle or a plunkr, so that I can see all of your html and js. Anyway it would help to see the original Error message in the console.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ownslo/Ld3xp8az/5/    <--- this contains the URL of the site, the HTML. and my current tampermonkey script.    I'm simply trying to make it click on each color, with the delay set to 10. It simply clicks the first class and none other. and thanks for helping me man.