# Deleting a node by class is not working in my Tampermonkey script?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I know how to remove a div by class (`document.getElementsByClassName('Button')[0].remove()`).
But when it is in a link:

```
<a class="Button" href=""><span>test</span></a>
```

it isn't working.

Why not?

Comment: You need to clarify what exactly you want to remove here.

Comment: Surprisingly, I couldn't find a good dupe target for this.  Maybe this Q&A can be the future target...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is *probably* that the page adds that link dynamically using javascript (AJAX).
<sup>(Also, the question code would only kill the *first* such node, and the one you want gone may be later.)</sup>

In that case, you need to use AJAX-compensating techniques such as `MutationObserver` or `waitForKeyElements` (or clunky hand-coded timers).

Here's a robust way (complete working script):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Remove node(s) with a specified class
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @noframes
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.
/* global $, waitForKeyElements */

waitForKeyElements (".Button", removeNode);

function removeNode (jNode) {
    jNode.remove ();
}
```

**Notes:**

1. `.Button` is the CSS and [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for nodes with the `Button` class.
2. The shown code removes all nodes with class `Button`.  To remove only the first node, use: `waitForKeyElements (".Button", removeNode, true);` -- but this is seldom needed.
3. See [Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site) for tips on identifying and refining selectors.