# How to sort a website list (That has poor id / sub-class identification)?

Tags: jquery, sorting, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm trying to make a Greasemonkey script that will redo the listing on the right hand side of the page so they list from A - Z no matter how they may be laid out to begin with.

The site is http://ustvgo.tv/ and the relevant HTML is:

```
<div id="recent-posts-3" class="mh-widget widget_recent_entries">
    <h4 class="mh-widget-title"><span class="mh-widget-title-inner">Recent Posts</span></h4>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://ustvgo.tv/fox-sports-1/">Fox Sports 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://ustvgo.tv/disneyxd/">DisneyXD</a></li>
        <!-- etc. -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

The `<a>` nodes have no ID's or subclasses.

I've got it to pull the text part of the link and to add it to a split array where the white spaces are but I for the life of me can't get it to spit out that array with the numbering so that I can add a new ID in front of the link text and still have the link text be the same as it was.

I.E. `<a href="http://ustvgo.tv/fox-sports-1/">Fox Sports 1</a>` would become `<a href="http://ustvgo.tv/fox-sports-1/">ID="name" Fox Sports 1</a>` that way I can have the script just sort the list by the name ID text A - Z.

How can I sort that list?

Comment: Couldn't find a dupe target for this common task.  Perhaps this question can become one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort a group of nodes:

1. First **identify the HTML that controls the display order**. <sup>(Note that if the visual order is changed via CSS, it can get complicated. Ask a new question for that.)</sup>
   In this case, it is the `<li>` elements.
2. Using [techniques like these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15052467/331508) **identify CSS/jQuery selectors** for those nodes and their container.
   In this case a selector for the container is: `#recent-posts-3 > ul` and
   a selector for the items is: `#recent-posts-3 > ul > li` (or `.find ("li")` on the container).
3. **Sort the nodes as desired** (typically on `textContent`).
   Reference [the `.localeCompare()` doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).
4. **Reappend the nodes to the container** in the sorted order.  Note that when you use `.appendChild()`, `.appendTo()`, etc. on an existing node, it *moves* that node to the new location.
5. Note that this Q&A is **for static pages**. Dynamic / javascript-loaded / AJAX-driven pages may require a different approach. Open a new question for that.

So, **here is a complete working Tampermonkey/Violentmonkey script** that sorts that column. (It probably works in Greasemonkey 4+ too, but [you should not use that engine anyway](https://www.greasespot.net/2017/09/greasemonkey-4-for-users.html)):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     USTVGO, sort "Recent Posts"
// @match    *://ustvgo.tv/*
// @noframes
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==
/* global jQuery, $ */
/* eslint-disable no-multi-spaces, curly */
'use strict';

var $ = jQuery;  //  The page loads jQuery (and we are in grant none mode), but doesn't set `$`.
var recentPostsLst  = $("#recent-posts-3 > ul");
var itemsToSort     = recentPostsLst.find ("li");

itemsToSort.sort (sortByLinkTextAscending).appendTo (recentPostsLst);

function sortByLinkTextAscending (nodeA, nodeB) {
     var valA_Text  = $(nodeA).find ("a").text ().trim ();
     var valB_Text  = $(nodeB).find ("a").text ().trim ();

     return valA_Text.localeCompare (valB_Text, 'en', {sensitivity: 'base'} );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked. I will study those things you linked for this so I can better understand what is going on there. As I as before I'm not against learning by asking, once I've hit a wall and can can't find a way to do it by reading and more reading and googling.