# “Selenium is not defined”?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I am trying to make it where every time I visit a FootLocker/FootAction etc../ sneaker page, it automatically picks my shoe size, adds it to the cart, and checks out for me. Every time I try to run the script, I keep getting this error

> ERROR: Execution of script 'My Fancy New Userscript' failed! selenium is not defined

Here is my script

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       FOOTLOCKER.ACTION
// @namespace  http://*/*
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @match      http://*/*
// @copyright  2012+, You
// ==/UserScript==

selenium.select("class=selectBox-label", "10"); // this selects size 10 
selenium.click("class=cmConversionEventSizeSelection");
selenium.waitForElement("class=addToCartButton"); 
selenium.click("class=addToCartButton");
selenium.waitForElement("class=checkout");
selenium.click("class=checkout")
```

Here is the [Target Page](http://pastebin.com/f8szYz1K)

Comment: What does this have to do with CSS?

Comment: @BoltClock Mind if I retag?

Comment: may be you can include the following @require annotation.

---@require https://github.com/Nthalk/SeleniumJQuery.git

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Selenium injects its code directly into the page, but your script runs in a sandbox/different scope.

Also this question is a duplicate of [Why does my Tampermonkey script throw "Selenium is not defined"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041365) and should be closed as such.